# COM DDL referenced is different between one machine and another

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Environment: 
Visual Studio 2017
Windows 7 vs Windows 10 (in my scenario)

Problem:
I created a simple class library targeting `.net fx 2.0` and referencing a `com dll` named `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 library`

```
Computer1 - Windows 10, VS 2017
Interop.ADODB version is 2.0.0.0

Computer2 - Windows 7, VS 2017
Interop.ADODB version is 4.0.0.0
```

Why the discrepency?

The behavior I'm looking for is what happens on Computer1, but I need that to happen on my `Windows 7 machine`.

[image]
I've tried where my solution also targeted .Net Framework 2 or 3.5 (but the project only targets .Net Framework 2) same thing happens.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but Computer 2 was a clean install of VS 2017 and Windows 7.

Comment: I tried the following on a virtual machine...I installed VS 2015 and VS 2017 on the same vm and I get the desired behavior in VS 2017 that way.